# Flickering cursor after resizing the window ( Monogame )

Tags: c#, monogame

I implemented custom resizing to an app ( to fix the no rendering while resizing thing ), and sometimes after resizing the cursor starts flickering.

The cursor is set this way:

```
public enum CursorCode {
            ...
        }

        public static CursorCode current = CursorCode.Default;

        public static void SetCursor ( CursorCode code ) {
            current = code;
            switch ( code ) {
                case CursorCode.ResizeNWSE:
                    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                    break;
...
            }
        }
```

It is not called to be set to anything else than I want.
It is called every frame ( to `current` ) and update.
It flicker only and only when I move the mouse. When I rest it, it stays as what the `current` is set to.

The window is resized this way:

```
var mx = beginX + Input.mouseX;
            var my = beginY + Input.mouseY;

            if ( toResize.Contains( Side.Right ) ) {
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Math.Min( Math.Max( mx, 50 ), dragWindow.area.Width );
            }

            if ( toResize.Contains( Side.Bottom ) ) {
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Math.Min( Math.Max( my, 50 ), dragWindow.area.Height );
            }

            if ( toResize.Contains( Side.Top ) ) {
                var h = graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Math.Min( Math.Max( my - Input.mouseY * 2, 50 ), dragWindow.area.Height );
                var delta = h - Math.Min( Math.Max( my - Input.mouseY * 2, 50 ), dragWindow.area.Height );
                Window.Position = new Point( Window.Position.X, Window.Position.Y + delta );
                beginY -= delta;
            }

            if ( toResize.Contains( Side.Left ) ) {
                var w = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth;
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Math.Min( Math.Max( mx - Input.mouseX * 2, 50 ), dragWindow.area.Width );
                var delta = w - Math.Min( Math.Max( mx - Input.mouseX * 2, 50 ), dragWindow.area.Width );
                Window.Position = new Point( Window.Position.X + delta, Window.Position.Y );
                beginX -= delta;
            }

            graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

After I finish resizing, the issue persists. It does not happen always.

Comment: Why don't you allow the window to be resizeable? `Window.AllowUserResizing = true;` And then add a handler to run any game related resize code: `Window.ClientSizeChanged += OnResize;`

Comment: It hangs up the rendering. I wrote this in the first sentence. Also my window is always borderless, which doesnt allow user resizing.